# How to add custom styles inside SilverStripe 4 CMS

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

Would anyone know what is the best way to add custom CSS for pages inside the CMS ?
I found we could do something like that, inside `config.yml`:

```
SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\TinyMCEConfig:
  base_dir: 'silverstripe/admin:thirdparty/tinymce'
    editor_css:
      - 'themes/base/build/bundle-editor.css'
```

but that's only linked to TinyMCE, and I would like to add my styles to all the pages in the CMS, or at least for the pages that uses `SilverStripe\Forms\TreeDropdownField` as it is broken:

TreeDropdownField broken

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a core bug, which has been fixed already and will be released in the next 4.0.x release (4.0.2), or 4.1.0.

More information: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-admin/issues/377

**Edit:** 4.0.2 has been released, so this should be resolved now.